# phpcs, phpcbf and loose comparisons

Tags: coding-standards

phpcs found many warnings about "Loose comparisons" and means, that phpcbf can these fix automatically. But phpcbf does not fixed them:

```
  93 | WARNING | [x] Loose comparisons are not allowed. Expected: "==="; Found: "=="
...
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 3 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
```

```
vendor/bin/phpcbf  --standard=WordPress admin.php 

No fixable errors were found

Time: 97ms; Memory: 12MB
```

Should phpcbf fix or not? If yes, how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if it doesn't do it automatically it's super easy to do manually, have you reported this to PHPCS/CBF? And are you using the latest and greatest v3.8 of PHPCS? Note that this isn't a PHPCS stack it's a WordPress stack

Comment: I know, there are commands to fix it, but I have some inline JavaScript that should be ignored. I use phpcs 3.8.0 and php 8.1. I have not reported this to PHPCS/CBF yet. I wanted to ask first if it should work, not that I have configured / installed something wrong.